navigationSplitViewColumnWidth being ignored. Cannot widen sidebar or detail column
I am trying to use NavigationSplitView to create a two-column structure where right column depends on left column and the left column is a bit larger than the right.  Thinking I might want the two columns to stack on a phone. For a simple example I'm using the same view in both columns.
No matter what I try to do I cannot get the left column to be wider than about 25% of an iPad in Landscape (or about 35% in portrait).  I need the left column to be more like 60% of the width.
I have tried:

Many variants of frames on the widget
Combinations of values for NavigationSplitViewVisibility.
Combinations of values for min,ideal,max signature for navigationSplitViewColumnWidth

The view is static so I must have .navigationSplitViewStyle(.balanced) and no toolbar.
Am I just using the wrong thing, should I use something instead of NavigationSplitView for a two-column view on an iPad in Landscape?
struct SuggestionContentView : View {
    @State var isPresented:Bool = false
    
    @State var items = [
        "crown",
        "cereal",
        "color",
        "cookie",
        "can",
        "cat",
    ]
    var nullAction: (() -> Void)?
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(items, id:\.self) { item in
                Button {
                    isPresented = true
                } label: {
                    Text(item)
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    }
}

Here is the layout with three columns and a zero-width sidebar:
struct ClickAndSuggestionLayout: View {
    @State private var columnVisibility =
    NavigationSplitViewVisibility.doubleColumn
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView(columnVisibility: $columnVisibility) {
            EmptyView().navigationSplitViewColumnWidth(0)
        } content: {
            SuggestionContentView()
                .toolbar(.hidden, for: .navigationBar)
                .navigationSplitViewColumnWidth( 800)
        } detail: {
            SuggestionContentView()
                .toolbar(.hidden, for: .navigationBar)
                .navigationSplitViewColumnWidth(400)
        }
        .navigationSplitViewStyle(.balanced)
    }
}

Here is the layout with two columns per online examples:
struct RadialAndSuggestionLayout: View {
    @State private var columnVisibility =
    NavigationSplitViewVisibility.doubleColumn
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView(columnVisibility: $columnVisibility) {
            SuggestionContentView()
                .toolbar(.hidden, for: .navigationBar)
                .navigationSplitViewColumnWidth( 800)
        } detail: {
            SuggestionContentView()
                .toolbar(.hidden, for: .navigationBar)
                .navigationSplitViewColumnWidth(400)
        }
        .navigationSplitViewStyle(.balanced)
    }
}

In both case I get previews like this:



From the documentation,

Only some platforms enable resizing columns. If you specify a width that the current presentation environment doesn’t support, SwiftUI may use a different width for your column.

navigationSplitViewColumnWidth is only just a "suggestion". SwiftUI has every right to not resize the column to the width you want. From my experiments, it seems like navigationSplitViewColumnWidth does not set maximumPrimaryColumnWidth of the underlying UISplitViewController at all, even if you pass a max: argument.
You will need to use the UISplitViewController APIs to make this work. Specifically, you need to set preferredPrimaryColumnWidth or preferredPrimaryColumnWidthFraction to your desired width, and maximumPrimaryColumnWidth to a big enough value.
For example, here is how you would do it using SwiftUI-Introspect.
NavigationSplitView {
    Color.blue
} detail: {
    Color.yellow
}
.introspect(.navigationSplitView, on: .iOS(.v16, .v17)) { splitView in
    splitView.maximumPrimaryColumnWidth = .infinity
    splitView.preferredPrimaryColumnWidthFraction = 2 / 3
}

Wrapping a UISplitViewController with UIViewControllerRepresentable is a more future-proof solution, though. Here is a simple example:
struct UIKitSplitView<Primary, Secondary, Selection>: UIViewControllerRepresentable
    where Primary : View, Secondary : View, Selection: Hashable {
    
    typealias UIViewControllerType = UISplitViewController
    
    let primary: Primary
    let secondary: Secondary
    let selection: Selection?
    
    init(selection: Selection?, @ViewBuilder primary: @escaping () -> Primary, @ViewBuilder secondary: @escaping () -> Secondary) {
        self.primary = primary()
        self.secondary = secondary()
        self.selection = selection
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UISplitViewController {
        
        let splitViewController = UISplitViewController(style: .doubleColumn)
        splitViewController.preferredPrimaryColumnWidth = 800
        splitViewController.maximumPrimaryColumnWidth = .infinity
        splitViewController.delegate = context.coordinator
        
        let primaryHostingViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: primary)
        let secondaryHostingViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: secondary)
                
        splitViewController.setViewController(primaryHostingViewController, for: .primary)
        splitViewController.setViewController(secondaryHostingViewController, for: .secondary)
                
        return splitViewController
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UISplitViewController, context: Context) { 
        (uiViewController.viewController(for: .primary) as! UIHostingController<Primary>).rootView = primary
        (uiViewController.viewController(for: .secondary) as! UIHostingController<Secondary>).rootView = secondary
        if let selection {
            uiViewController.show(.secondary)
        }
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator()
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UISplitViewControllerDelegate {
        func splitViewController(_ svc: UISplitViewController, topColumnForCollapsingToProposedTopColumn proposedTopColumn: UISplitViewController.Column) -> UISplitViewController.Column {
            return .primary
        }
    }
}

Example Usage:
struct ContentView: View
{
    @State var selection: Int?
    
    var body: some View {
        // the "selection" parameter here acts as a trigger for showing the detail view
        // when "selection" is not nil, the detail view is shown
        UIKitSplitView(selection: selection) {
            List([1,2,3,4], id: \.self, selection: $selection) {
                Text("Row \($0)")
            }
        } secondary: {
            if let selection {
                Text("Details for \(selection)")
            }
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        
    }
}


Appreciate the answer, I wound up just using an HStack for now since I don't have a specific design for phones yet.

Appreciate Sweeper’s answer.
Here’s the 3-column style version if anyone needs it.
The view provides using custom divider color and a closure for configuring the split view from inside the SwiftUI initializer.
struct UIKitSplitView<Primary, Supplementary, Secondary>: UIViewControllerRepresentable
where Primary: View, Supplementary: View, Secondary: View {
    
    private final class MySplitViewController: UISplitViewController {
        var onColorSchemeChange: ((MySplitViewController) -> Void)?
        
        override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
            super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)
            
            if traitCollection.hasDifferentColorAppearance(comparedTo: previousTraitCollection) {
                onColorSchemeChange?(self)
            }
        }
    }

    @Binding var columnVisibility: UISplitViewController.DisplayMode
    let dividerColor: UIColor?
    let primary: Primary
    let supplementary: Supplementary
    let secondary: Secondary
    let configureSplitView: ((UISplitViewController) -> Void)?

    init(columnVisibility: Binding<UISplitViewController.DisplayMode>,
         dividerColor: UIColor? = nil,
         configure: ((UISplitViewController) -> Void)? = nil,
         @ViewBuilder primary: @escaping () -> Primary,
         @ViewBuilder supplementary: @escaping () -> Supplementary,
         @ViewBuilder secondary: @escaping () -> Secondary) {
        self._columnVisibility = columnVisibility
        self.dividerColor = dividerColor
        self.primary = primary()
        self.supplementary = supplementary()
        self.secondary = secondary()
        self.configureSplitView = configure
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UISplitViewController {
        let splitViewController = MySplitViewController(style: .tripleColumn)

        // Allow configuration through closure if provided
        configureSplitView?(splitViewController)

        splitViewController.delegate = context.coordinator

        let primaryHostingViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: primary)
        let supplementaryHostingViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: supplementary)
        let secondaryHostingViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: secondary)

        splitViewController.setViewController(primaryHostingViewController, for: .primary)
        splitViewController.setViewController(supplementaryHostingViewController, for: .supplementary)
        splitViewController.setViewController(secondaryHostingViewController, for: .secondary)
        
        splitViewController.preferredSplitBehavior = .tile
        
        splitViewController.preferredDisplayMode = columnVisibility
        
        if let dividerColor {
            splitViewController.view.backgroundColor = dividerColor
            splitViewController.onColorSchemeChange = { splitViewController in
                splitViewController.view.backgroundColor = dividerColor
            }
        }
        
        return splitViewController
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UISplitViewController, context: Context) {
        (uiViewController.viewController(for: .primary) as! UIHostingController<Primary>).rootView = primary
        (uiViewController.viewController(for: .supplementary) as! UIHostingController<Supplementary>).rootView = supplementary
        (uiViewController.viewController(for: .secondary) as! UIHostingController<Secondary>).rootView = secondary
        
        // prevent unnecessary updates causing animation glitches
        if columnVisibility != context.coordinator.lastKnownDisplayMode, uiViewController.preferredDisplayMode != columnVisibility {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
                uiViewController.preferredDisplayMode = columnVisibility
            }
        }
        
        if let dividerColor {
            uiViewController.view.backgroundColor = dividerColor
            (uiViewController as! MySplitViewController).onColorSchemeChange = { splitViewController in
                splitViewController.view.backgroundColor = dividerColor
            }
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UISplitViewControllerDelegate {
        let parent: UIKitSplitView
        // Record the updated display mode from the delegate method.
        // This helps differentiate between changes made by the UISplitViewController itself and changes from the SwiftUI Binding.
        private(set) var lastKnownDisplayMode: UISplitViewController.DisplayMode
        
        init(_ parent: UIKitSplitView) {
            self.parent = parent
            self.lastKnownDisplayMode = parent.columnVisibility
        }
        
        // required to prevent crashing from going from background to foreground
        func splitViewController(_ svc: UISplitViewController, topColumnForCollapsingToProposedTopColumn proposedTopColumn: UISplitViewController.Column) -> UISplitViewController.Column {
            return .primary
        }
        
        func splitViewController(_ svc: UISplitViewController, willChangeTo displayMode: UISplitViewController.DisplayMode) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.lastKnownDisplayMode = displayMode
                self.parent.columnVisibility = displayMode
            }
        }
    }
}


